# Regex matching and printing perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl and i did lot of research on regex to get it right but i'm not able to.

I have an output from a Linux box, when a user chooses test as the VG it should print 4.99g which is the free size left on that particular volume group.

```
# vgs
VG    #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 
test    1   3   0 wz--n- 19.99g  4.99g
test1   1   0   0 wz--n- 19.99g  50.00m
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to extract field #14. Try split and extract field. What have you tried? Please show your code

Comment: Sorry, initially when i posted the command output format was wrong.

Comment: Ok :) then its field #7 on line2 ? Try `perl -anE 'say $F[6] if $. == 2' vgs`

Comment: This works perfectly.
#vgs |perl -anE 'say $F[6] if $. == 2' 
4.99g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract field #7 on line 2 of file `vgs`:

```
perl -anE 'say $F[6] if $. == 2' vgs
```

Comment: What if i have a list of volume groups under VG and say test, test1, user, user1, group, group1 and STDIN from user is group1. Now how would i accomplish to print the #7 corresponding to group1 ?

Comment: Try checking if field #1 is equal to `group1`: `perl -anE 'say $F[6] if $F[0] eq "group1"' vgs`

Comment: Hi, I need your help again. You gave me a one liner which works perfectly and now i'm trying to put the same in a script.

Comment: @sharath Hello. Feel free to contact me by email if you need further assistance with this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have come till here but not getting an output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@vg = system(vgs);
print "Enter the vg name: ";
chomp($vgname = <STDIN>);

@values = split (' ', $vg);
foreach $line (@values)
{
   if ($vgname eq $line[0])
   {
      print "$line[5]"
   }
}
```